# Pandas - Delete all fields except column values not matches email

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to create a new data frame from an existing data frame with values of row match email based on a regular expression.

```
import pandas as pd
data= pd.read_excel("path to file")
from validate_email import validate_email
#i wish to get some code as follows, it is not correct, I added it for your reference
new_data_frame = data[data.Email == validate_email('column value')]
```

I am adding a screenshot for reference, I am trying to get all rows with email:

[image: delete all rows except email]

Could anyone provide the correct solution?

Comment: new_data_frame = data.loc[data['column value'].apply(validate_email)]

Comment: Is your real question how to write a function like `is_valid_email` ?

Comment: You can see the date fields in the data frame ( please see image), I want to filter it out with only emails. i.e remove fields except emails from the data frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume validate_email is a function that takes in an email and return true/false. In that case you are looking for `.apply` which applies a function on a column, row or frame.

Look at this example:

```
import pandas as pd

def validate_email(email):
    return '@' in email

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'email': ['test@gmail.com', 'nonvalid']
})

new_df = df.loc[df['email'].apply(validate_email)]

print(new_df)
```

Returns:

```
            email
0  test@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to check whether it is an email

```
    import re
    EMAIL_REGEX = re.compile(r"[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+")
    bool(EMAIL_REGEX.match('abc@gmail.com'))
    bool(EMAIL_REGEX.match('26/07/17'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am already using it from the function validate_email mentioned in the code above